# Task Scheduled not running batch file

Tags: windows, windows-7, vbscript, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have file which does somethings and it works fine if I run the file manually but it doesn't run when set up in task scheduler.

Batch file is in a folder on desktop on windows 7.

Any feedback will be helpful.

I've even tried [this link](http://www.blogfodder.co.uk/2012/4/20/win-2008-task-scheduler-with-return-code-1-0x1) solution didn't work.

Comment: When you say that something didn't work, you have to say how it didn't work. Not enough information in your question to give any suggestions.

Comment: Is the task running under a different user? Is "run with highest privileges" enabled? What does your script look like? Did you already add some logging/debugging code to it?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Task is running as same user (me) with `highest privileges` enabled. My script works fine, I've tested it manually(it works if I double click batch file).

Comment: @AbqBill I meant it doesn't do that is it supposed to do. my script calls wget which is in same folder as my batch file is, and that sends email to me. asI said it works if I double click the batch file but not via task scheduler, I don't know why it doesn't work via task scheduler.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely in this case you need to make sure that the directory the script runs in ("Start in") is set correctly.  Usually this is the same directory that contains your script.  You can set this in the Scheduled Task's properties.

Comment: I added my directory path in start in field? that is what you mean, it still didn't work. `C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\GnuWin32\bin` and my `bat` file is in same folder.

Comment: Because you're using GnuWin332, you also need to check your PATH settings to be sure it includes what's necessary for GnuWin32 to work.  You'll need check with that project for what's required. http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: I have tried that, I read on some site, it is not issue with PATH.

Answer (score 0):

As a test, try moving the .bat file to a directory with basic permissions (maybe a shared directory for example).

I had the same problem as you. My .bat file was located in a folder with some restrictive permissions on it, so that only my user account could access it. Even though I had set up the task scheduler to use my credentials it still failed. Moving the .bat file to another directory sorted the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but in bashing my head against one problem after another for far too many hours, I finally got my own batch file to work properly as a scheduled task.  Some of the things I learned in the process:

1. If you are the user who has created the scheduled task, you must also be a user who has logged into the system using a password.
2. Any reference to a file name, inside the batch file, needs to be the last part of fully qualified path, starting with drive letter.
3. If you do a comparison, like [%flag%] EQU [0], be aware that the "[" and "]" symbols are string literals that are included in the data that gets compared.
4. If part of your batch file sets a variable and includes a "FOR" loop that calls a subroutine in which you expect to change the variable, you need to make sure that the variable is originally initialized as early as possible in the batch file.  That is, something like this:

   ```
   IF ... (
     SET %flag=0
     FOR ... (CALL :subr)
     IF [%flag%] EQU [1] ( main scheduled-task command goes here)
   )
   GOTO :eof

   :subr
     IF ... (SET %flag=1)

   :eof
   ```

--worked from the command line, but not as a Scheduled Task.  I had to move the initialization of %flag to be done before that very-first IF.